# Crystal Report using local dataset with SQL Expression in the report

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

(Visual Studio 2008, VB.NET Winform Application, SQL Server, Crystal Reports)

I'm having trouble with this setup:  I've created a vb.net app that creates a local dataset using two different data tables as well as adding some columns for other values queried from another table or two.  The resultant table is just what i need for my crystal report.

Inside the report, I've used a few SQL Expression fields to pull some values in for calculations.

I call the report from the vb app, in this code:

> Dim rpt As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
>
> rpt.Load(RptNameString)
>
> rpt.SetDatabaseLogon(user, crystalpw)
>
> rpt.SetDataSource(DS1.Tables(0))
>
> rpt.SetParameterValue("prmUserName", txtWinUsername)
>
> rpt.SetParameterValue("prmReportname", "rptBackLog.rpt")
>
> frmPrintPreview.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt
>
> frmPrintPreview.Show()

When this report loads, it immediately throws up a Crystal Reports error saying "SQL Expressions can not be used in this report."

Normally i create my dataset within CR, but this one is just too complicated and needs some building on the vb side prior to running.

Any advice/suggestions/answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're going to use the PUSH model...why don't you have columns that are the results of any computations..and go 100% PUSH.  That's the best way to do these I think (IMHO), because you can Unit-Test a dataset....  Use CR for what it does, as a presentation layer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yes that is what i ended up having to do.  CR has so many powerful features it's sometimes hard to decide what to do before the information hits the presentation layer.